# sqlite - how to combine overall count and group by?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, group-by

I have the following table of PHOTOS, their times and months:

```
TIME|MONTH|PHOTO
----|-----|-----
 x1 | mx1 | p1
 x2 | mx2 | p2
 ...
```

I'd like to get all months sorted descendent BUT, with the total photos count up until that month - not just the count of that month's group.

For example, the following query isn't good enough as it returns the count of each specific month's group instead of the total count up until that group:

```
select MONTH, count(TIME) from PHOTOS group by MONTH sort by MONTH desc
```

Ideas?

Comment: Do you have primary key for the table?

Comment: @tvelykyy - Why does this matter? lets keep this simple.

Comment: okay:) I've posted solution without using any primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite has less functionalities compared to other RDBMS but I think this is how you should do it:

```
SELECT photosA.month,
       (SELECT COUNT(time) AS PhotoCounter
        FROM   photos AS photosB 
        WHERE  photosB.month <= photosA.month) AS total_photos
FROM   photos AS photosA
GROUP BY photosA.month
```

ciao!

Comment: Works. Added order by: `order by photosA.month desc`. Tested on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/de7f1/7

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka you have to formulate better input constraints for you problem. You've posted problem with string months and accepted solution with integer months.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.month, count(b.month) as CountSmaller
from  [PHOTOS] a
inner join [PHOTOS] b on b.[MONTH] <= a.[MONTH]
group by a.time, a.month, a.photo
order by 2 desc
```

tested in sqlfiddle

Comment: SUM(Time) does not make sense. The question asks for the count of photos.

Comment: Your answer won't work if we use real months names due to lexicographical comparison used in your query.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/abbe8/1/0

Comment: The months and times are integers so ok to compare them using `<=`

Comment: Not what I was looking for. I searched to get just the months and the count of photos - not an entry for each photo.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/812ac/2/0

To solve your problem, firstly you need some kind of month order. You can do it by this query:

```
select 1 id, 'mx1' m
union
select 2, 'mx2'
union
select 3, 'mx3'
union
select 4, 'mx4'
```

You can do it in every query by nested query or create separate table.
And manipulating nested queries, aggregate function and joins you can achieve your goal by:

```
select m2,
(
    select count(*) from photos p
    inner join 
    (
      select 1 id, 'mx1' month
      union
      select 2, 'mx2'
      union
      select 3, 'mx3'
      union
      select 4, 'mx4'
    ) m
    on p.month = m.month and m.id <= M.id2
)

from
(
    select 1 id2, 'mx1' m2
    union
    select 2, 'mx2'
    union
    select 3, 'mx3'
    union
    select 4, 'mx4'
) M
```

If you have any questions I can answer them in comments.

Comment: You should map each month to some number. There is no other way. We have only 12 months available, so there is no big deal.